# How do I load my USB device to show songs at boot-up?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am running my code at raspberry pi boot-up by executing the file in /etc/profile. It works fine. But, I want to attach a pendrive and load songs to show in my GUI using os.walk(). This doesn't work. What do I do?

```
def music_file(self):
     for media, dirs, files in os.walk('/media/pi/'):
        for filename in files:
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".mp3":
                os.path.join(media, filename)
                self.filename1.append(os.path.join(media, filename))
                self.filename2.append(filename)
    for home, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/pi/'):
        for filename in files:
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".mp3":
                os.path.join(media, filename)
                self.filename1.append(os.path.join(home, filename))
                self.filename2.append(filename)
    return self.filename2
```

Comment: `This doesn't work` – any specific error?

Comment: @Alderven No error. But the .mp3 files just don't load in the list. Once I escape the execution of my code using startx, the raspbian window loads and then the media device gets detected.

Answer (score 1):

What you present us is just a function. It is not clear how you call it.

However, it seems to me that there are some minor issues in it which could lead to the output being unusable.

Let's have a closer look:

- The part

  ```
  for media, dirs, files in os.walk('/media/pi/'):
      for filename in files:
          if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".mp3":
              os.path.join(media, filename)
              self.filename1.append(os.path.join(media, filename))
              self.filename2.append(filename)
  ```

  is (in variants) used twice, so let's put that into a separate function.
- There is a `self.filename1` and a `self.filename2` which hold different things: one holds the full path, the other only the base name. The latter is nice to display, but your programs won't find these files. And the base name can easily be derived from the full path, so let's use the full path.

  ```
  def music_tree(*bases): # can be a @staticmethod or a normal function outside of any class
      for base in bases:
          for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base):
              for filename in files:
                  if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".mp3":
                      # os.path.join(root, filename) # useless, omit that
                      yield os.path.join(media, filename)
  def music_file(self):
      for path in music_tree('/media/pi/', '/home/pi'):
          self.filename1.append(path)
          self.filename2.append(os.path.basename(path))
          yield path # here, the caller might iterate over the function result (generator object) and get the paths one by one as they are found
      return self.filename1 # instead of 2, depeding on what the caller wants to do with the list
  ```

Comment: As I mentioned, the output of these functions work fine. It's just that the os.walk() function doesn't seemed to get called when it's a part of my code that is run at boot. Once, I escape the executon and OS gets load then the pendrive gets detected.

Comment: @AbhishekTaori Then the error might be at a completely different level. What does "code that is run at boot" mean? Is it maybe called in the /etc/init.d/ system or systemd (whichever of them runs on the RasPi) before the USB detection happens? Then maybe this needs to be altered.

Comment: Yes. I call it in /etc/profile. Is there a way to USB detection? What do I do to alter it?

Comment: @AbhishekTaori Here I am out. According to my knowledge, when executing `/etc/profile`, the USB should be present, so I don't know what could be the problem. Maybe someone else…